# Dismissing all view controllers that is presented modalPresentationStyle = .custom

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 view controllers. 
1. ViewController
2. InitialViewController
3. FinalViewController

ViewController is added to a navigation controller. ViewController's modalPresentationStyle is `custom`. ViewController presents InitialViewController. InitialViewController's modalPresentationStyle is `custom` too. InitialViewController presents FinalViewController. FinalViewController modalPresentationStyle is `custom` too. FinalViewController presents InitialViewController (yes, second time with updated UI). InitialViewController presents another instance of FinalViewController.

The final arrangement looks like this

```
NavigationController -> ViewController (presents) -> InitialViewController 1 (presents) -> FinalViewController 1 (presents) -> InitialViewController 2 (presents) -> FinalViewController 2.
```

When I dismiss FinalViewController 2 by calling

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I still have the TransitionViews of InitialViewController 1, FinalViewController 1, InitialViewController 2. InitialViewController 2 is still around. (As seen in the picture) 
[image]

I understand that this can be removed by calling

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But by doing this the FinalViewController 2's dismissal is not animated. Do I need another Custom transition for this dismissal?

Comment: I guess you have to create custom callback of each dismissal of VC and perform the  animation accordingly.

Comment: what is the actual effect you want？